# Wish to copy a cv layout

Tags: cv, currvita

could anyone help me create this cv layout in latex?

[image]

Comment: We usually frown on "do this for me".  Could you make a first attempt at doing it yourself, and showing us what you get and what you have trouble with?  Also, how much do you want to match what you showed?  The images and color shading can be done, but are more complicated (and mostly not related to the "structure" of what you've shown).

Comment: You seem to be wishing to copy the vita of [LianTze Lim](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/226/liantze-lim), who is a frequent and extremely competent contributor to this site. She is also  the resident TeXpert over at overleaf.com. Are you trying to impersonate her?

Comment: no way!!! I simply like her structure for CV, but her way of presenting it seems very difficult to understand . I search  a simple way to creat it

Comment: For example: the title with the line down in green, I  do not know how to do it

Comment: probably you can find the template at https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/cv

Comment: @samcarter - Indeed, her cv template may be found at https://www.overleaf.com/gallery/tagged/cv/page/6.

Comment: Wow @Mico, thank you for your very, very kind words! @solid indeed if you go and open up the CV's source code "Open as template", most of the commands/configs are in the `settings.sty` file. Specifically the code for the green (colour can be changed) swishy line is on lines 66–69. In LaTeX you often have to dive into .sty and .cls code if you want to discover how to do things yourself. Just sayin'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many cv templates around, but it is also not very difficult to create a cv layout from scratch using standard LaTeX commands.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}
\newcommand\heading[3]%
  {\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
   \sffamily\bfseries\LARGE#1\\
   \small\Letter\ \texttt{#2}
   \end{tabular}%
   \hfill
   \includegraphics[height=10ex]{#3}%
   \vspace{2ex}%
  }
\newcommand\secline
  {\tikz\fill[green,path fading=east] (0,0) rectangle (\linewidth,2pt);}
\renewcommand\section[1]%
  {\par\bigskip
   {\sffamily\bfseries\large#1}\\[-1.5ex]
   \secline
   \par\bigskip
  }
\newcommand\cventry[3]%
  {\makebox[5em][l]{#1}\hspace{1em}%
   \parbox[t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-6em}%
   {\textbf{#2}\quad#3}%
   \par\medskip
  }
\parindent0pt

\begin{document}

\heading{Some Body, Ph.D.}{some.body@some.where}{example-image-1x1.png}

\section{Employment History}

\cventry{2014 -- $\cdots$}{Software developer.}{Many hugely successful projects
  that I sold to Google. Bla bla bla bla bla bla.}

\cventry{2013 -- 2015}{Waiter.}{Serving tea, coffee, and burgers.}

\end{document}
```